Getting Rid of Boolean Flags
I really appreciate the combination of using CanExecute, NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor, and AsyncRelayCommand<T>.IsRunning property to run/stop the ActivityIndicator and disable/enable the Command button without having to keep track of boolean properties allover the ViewModel, as described in this excellent blog post.
Yet, I'm left wondering, how about all other flags?
For example, the following code sample supports a XAML file that contains a single Picker Control (No buttons here). Before loading the Collection, the ActivityIndicator needs to run and the Picker has to be disabled, and after the collection is loaded, the flags are reversed. As the app gets complicated, other flags will have to be added.
Is there a better way out there to accomplish those tasks without relying on boolean flags?
public partial class TestViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Book _selectedBook;

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Book> _books;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool _showIndicator;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool _pickerEnabled;

    public TestViewModel()
    {           
        BooksService();
    }

    async Task BooksService()
    {
        ShowIndicator = true;
        PickerEnabled = false; //by default

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Books = await FetchBooks();

        ShowIndicator = false;
        PickerEnabled = true;
    }
}


Do you want less flags? You  may try using  Binding value converters.

As @LiqunShen-MSFT suggested in the comment, I ended up relying on converters. But instead of writing my own, I utilized pre-built ones available in the .NET Maui Community Toolkit. Specifically IsListNullOrEmptyConverter and IsListNotNullOrEmptyConverter.
<Grid>
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="20" Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Picker Title="Select Book" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Books, 
                        Converter={StaticResource IsListNotNullOrEmptyConverter}}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

    <ActivityIndicator
        IsVisible="{Binding Books, 
                    Converter={StaticResource IsListNullOrEmptyConverter}}"
        IsRunning="{Binding Books, 
                    Converter={StaticResource IsListNullOrEmptyConverter}}" />
</Grid>


Glad you solved it and thanks for your sharing! @usefulBee! Another small suggestion if you want to customize your own Converter, that is Using converter parameters.
Suppose you have many flags, then you may write many converters. If you use Converter Parameters, you may put all the logic in one Converter depending on the Parameters, such as
<Label
    Text="{Binding MyText,Converter={StaticResource myconverter},ConverterParameter=IsListNotNullOrEmpty}"

for the customized Converter
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        
        if((string)parameter == "IsListNotNullOrEmpty")
        {
            //your logic

        }else if((string)parameter == "b") 
        {
            //your logic
        }
        ...

    }

The above is a little suggestion from me. And .NET Maui Community Toolkit is strong!
